# UWP application claims it references its own exe during release build - "Manifest references file '' which is not part of the payload"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, visual-studio-2017

For example, in this case I have created a simple test application, the project is called "UWPSensorTest".

When I try to build in release, I get the error `Manifest references file 'UWPSensorTest.exe' which is not part of the payload.` Which is, of course, absurd. I can build in Debug just fine

The steps for me to reproduce this in my current enviroment is

1) Create new UWP projet

2) Switch to Release

3) Build

Comment: Are you running the latest version of Visual Studio 2017 (15.9.3) ?

Comment: @MartinZikmund Yes I am running the latest version of VS2017. I have also tested building the same project in release on another machine and it worked just fine.

Comment: In that case try complete unisntall of Visual Studio and reinstall. It is clearly a machine specific problem

Answer (score 0):

EDITTED:
or try to check that bug:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/collaborate/connect-redirect

Seems like a bad installation problem. 
open your Visual Studio Installer, and choose repair. (if update is available, Ill recommend you to update to the latest VS version) 
[image]

and after then to update your Windows 10 SDK (UWP Inculded) from [Microsoft's website](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk):

Or if you need a specific SDK version, just repair your current one

Comment: My Windows 10 SDK is the latest version, so I just tried repairing that - if the problem persists I'll repair VS itself